# Tricky conditional regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse some Textile content:

```
sample_1 =
"""
Pretext

h1. Primary Header

h2. Secondary Header

Content

"""

sample_2 =
"""
Pretext

h1. Primary Header

h2. Secondary Header

Content

h1. Another Primary Header
"""
```

The regular expressions below both give the same, correct output:

```
p sample_1.match(/(h1\. Primary Header.*)$$/m)[1] #-> "h1. Primary Header\n\nh2. Secondary Header\n\nContent\n\n"
p sample_2.match(/(h1\. Primary Header.*)h1/m)[1] #-> "h1. Primary Header\n\nh2. Secondary Header\n\nContent\n\n"
```

How can I use a single regular expression for both these cases? The following doesn't work, but I'm not sure why:

```
p sample_1.match(/(h1\. Primary Header.*)h1|$$/m)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h1\. Primary Header.*?(?=""")
```

dotall + multiline 
tested with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

The reason your combined regex doesn't work is because the .* operator is greedy, so the regexp will match multiple sections.

You could avoid this by using the non-greedy `.*?` operator.

more likely you should be using the .split instead of .match:

```
sample_2.split(/(?=^h1\.)/).drop(0)
```

Using a lookahead so that the split happens before the heading, instead of containing it.